# Why does Haskell need to have IO/Actions even though it's lazy-evaluation?

Tags: haskell

I suppose this may be a controversial topic because I touch the language design deeply, and I know some one around won't like that because they misunderstand I deny some virtue of what they like.

Why does Haskell need to have [IO/Actions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Introduction_to_Haskell_IO/Actions) even though it's [lazy-evaluation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_evaluation)?

I understand the value of IO/Actions mechanism to hold so-called "purity" of functional programming if it's for an eager-evaluating language such as C, JavaScript or any others.

In fact, I did emulate/implement `IO ()` in Typescript that evaluates eagerly, then I thought "Ok, cool, but why does Haskell need this??"

Haskell is lazy in default, therefore even the function is defined as

`print` == `console.log`

in JavaScript syntax, in Haskell since it's lazy, `print` won't be executed in anyway unless it's connected to `main :: IO ()`.

Any thoughts?

Edit:

Apparently, this question arises from total misconception of mine.

In Haskell, it defined as

`print` == `console.log`

`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()  -- Defined in ‘System.IO’`

I simply misunderstood as if defined as

`print :: Show a => a -> _ -> IO ()`

because it's needed to be so to emulate in eager evaluation.

Comment: `IO` also guarantees evaluating items in a certain *order*. Due to laziness, depending on what is necessary, some expressions are not (fully) evaluated. But for certain operations that is a problem: if you are parsing a file then it should parse the stream in a certain order.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's another questionable point to me. I've read the same explanation as you told here, but as long as I understand, the execution order is obtained by `>>=` sequence. The binary operation  guarantee **left->right order**. "Due to laziness" here simply mentions **top->down order** correct?

Comment: Or, do you suggest something about complete-state of IO actions? such as **IOa done -> IOb done** won't be  guaranteed even in `>>=` if it's defined like `console.log`?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right: the order is obtained by the `>>=` sequence. And that's exactly what monads are for. They require the use of `>>=` for composition, thus creating evaluation order. Non-monadic values don't require the use of `>>=`, so there is no order guarantee.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Well, thanks for the confirmation, and still, inside of the monad binary operation, it's doing, in JS,  `bind = f => IOa => f(IOa());` and  I wonder why the `()` of  `IOa()` is required in any Lazy-language. That's my point.

Comment: I mean `>>=` or `bind` binary operation can be composed without IO/Action because any values in Haskell is lazy. It's like lazy on lazy. Redundant it seems.

Comment: one point I'm surprised that hasn't been mentioned yet - the `IO` type comes with a *guarantee* (well, barring `unsafePerformIO` and related Bad Things) that nothing that doesn't have `IO` in the type signature can *ever* perform any side effects of any kind. That's really nice because it encourages programmers to think about which parts of their program actually need to interact with the outside world and minimise those, writing most of their applications in pure code that then becomes much easier to test and refactor and so on. (continued in next comment...)

Comment: And you can call a function and know just from the type signature that it's impossible for it to do anything unexpected. In other languages you're just taking it on trust that `getFoo` library function you're calling isn't going to make a network request. There's no danger in Haskell, for example, that a string interpolation function in a logging framework might be open to remote code execution vulnerabilities ;)

Comment: @RobinZigmond "one point I'm surprised that hasn't been mentioned yet - the IO type comes with a guarantee" Well, surprisingly, actually, I mentioned. "I understand the value of IO/Actions mechanism to hold so-called "purity" of functional programming if it's for an eager-evaluating language such as C, JavaScript or any others."

Comment: As far as I know, `unsafePerformIO` is extremely tricky concept and actually it reveals the matter of compiler or low-level implementations of the language which should not revealed to the Haskell programmers who do abstractions. Honestly, I wonder if it's really "unsafe" after it's implemented in some adequate matter.

Comment: @RobinZigmond See my edit of the Q.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've mixed things up! Haskell doesn't need `IO` in *spite* of laziness, it needs it *because* of laziness.

Let's imagine for a second that we don't have `IO` (or, equivalently, that everything that does `IO` is implicitly wrapped by `unsafePerformIO`). So, for example, I might write:

```
main = print (readLn + readLn)
```

This would get two lines of input from the user, parse them as numbers, add them up, and print the result. Nice! No problem so far. Now I decide I want to implement a little language. The thing I want to do is read a couple -- say, 5 -- of variable/value pairs from the user, stick them in a `Map`, and then read an expression from the user that might mention those variables. So an interaction with the user might look like

```
> 5
> 32
> 17
> -6
> 72
> (x1 + x4) * (x0 + x3)
< -104
```

where `>` marks lines I type in and `<` marks lines the program prints. The answer is -104 because x1=32, x4=72, x0=5, and x3=-6. The binding for x2=17 isn't used. Okay, let's write it.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

interpret :: M.Map String Int -> String -> Int
interpret = {- not relevant, really... right? -}

main = interpret env expr where
    env = M.fromList [("x0", readLn), ("x1", readLn), ("x2", readLn), ("x3", readLn), ("x4", readLn)]
    expr = getLine
```

Okay, now, pop quiz: what does this program do? Well, if we are taking laziness seriously, then all those `getLine`s are deferred until somebody actually looks at them. And if anybody's looking, who is it? It's `interpret`! So, to know what this program does, we actually do have to know what `interpret` does. Okay, let's start filling it out:

```
interpret env s = case parseExpr s of
    Just expr -> evaluateArithmetic (replaceVariables env expr)
    Nothing -> 404 -- lol
```

...aaaand, now we're in trouble. For a *bunch* of reasons, actually. Because the first thing `interpret` does is it evaluates `s`, which means *the first line the user types actually plays the role of the expression, not the last line*. So that's kind of unfortunate, but okay, maybe we just decide that's fine and reimagine our ideal interaction to conform to these implementation details:

```
> (x1 + x4) * (x0 + x3)
> 5
> 32
> 17
> -6
> 72
< -104
```

But even if we give up on the dream of putting the expression last, we're *still* in trouble. Because look what `replaceVariables` does:

```
data Expr = Lit Int | Var String | Add Expr Expr | Times Expr Expr

replaceVariables env (Lit n) = Lit n
replaceVariables env (Var v) = Lit (env M.! v)
replaceVariables env (Add x y) = Add (replaceVariables env x) (replaceVariables env y)
replaceVariables env (Times x y) = Times (replaceVariables env x) (replaceVariables env y)
```

Did you spot it? With the expression the user typed in, `x1` is the first variable it tries to replace -- meaning that *it is the first `readLn` that gets executed*, and instead of being 32, the second number we entered, as we intended, it is 5, the first number we entered. Similarly, x4 becomes 32 instead of 72, etc. and we get a just plain wrong answer. (Also, the program replies after we enter the fourth number without waiting for the fifth. But maybe that's not such a big deal.)

So this is the crux of the problem: without `IO`, the programmer has much less control over what order interactions with the user happen in. There's a follow-on problem that we didn't explore here, which is that not only is there little control, but that *refactoring can change the interface* -- if we made `replaceVariables` swap the arguments to `Add` for some reason, even though this really seems like a change that shouldn't affect anything, it makes the order that lines get read from the user even more different and confusing!

This is the core problem that `IO` solves. The implementation of `(>>=)` adds a data dependency that prevents later computations from executing until earlier ones finish. This means that when we write

```
main = readLn >>= \x -> {- rest of the program -}
```

we can be sure that `x` contains the contents of the first line the user types in, not some other line determined by the structure of the entire rest of the program.

Having to understand entire programs at once to know what small chunks of it do just doesn't work at scale!

Comment: Thank you as always. First of all, I don't deny the advantage of the  type of `IO` nor Monads. Actually, a person commented me as if I insisted that. Secondly, IMO, I doubt `unsafePerformIO` is really unsafe as they advertised because it's a matter of implementation of the run-time and I double if it's mathematically legitimate to call unsafe in principle. So far, I edit my Q and mention Clean-lang. I'm studying your code, but have a hard time to figure out what is really fundamental factor. Probably I ask too much, but can't it be more concise?

Comment: @Functor Sure, it can be more concise, but then it's less convincing. But since you asked: if I write `[getLine, getLine]` in my program, and I type in `"a\nb\n"`, do I get `["a", "b"]` or `["b", "a"]`? In the presence of laziness, either is possible, and that makes it hard to write a correct program.

Comment: @Functor As for whether it's "legitimate" to call `unsafePerformIO` unsafe, well, saying what is unsafe about it in a way a beginner can understand requires more exposition than will fit in a comment. But rest assured that you can give a crisp, precise notion of safety that is violated by `unsafePerformIO`, no matter how it's implemented in the runtime.

Comment: Thanks, in fact, after a couple of days of this Q.A., I start thinking I misunderstood from the first. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Firstly, I emulated the thunk mechanism in JavaScript eager-evaluation in the source-code level like `const print = a => () => console.log(a)` and I thought in Haskell `print` was implemented in the same manner at large, but the fact is `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`

Comment: So, in Haskell, actually,  `print 5`  is the same league of `5`, simply values and just type is different which  totally makes sense.

Comment: @Functor That all sounds right so far.

Comment: Great, not it does make sense. Thanks again.